# Invalid search region in United States

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

We are facing with search region issue with searching school/university type places.

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .noFilter
```

After query search by *findAutocompletePredictions()*. Results has been filtered by types below:

```
 let schoolTypes = ["primary_school", "secondary_school", "school", "university"]
```

Users from United States reporting us issue and they can not find Harvard university. They have to query "Boston univer"
If we query "Harv" first result is correct.
Our location is Europe. I've tested different scenario on Simulator, by changing region, language, keyboard or location on my computer and i'm getting correct response.
What settings should i check? Any ideas?

Correct Response:
[image: Correct response]

Incorrect response:

[image: IncorrectResponse]

Comment: I change `filter.type = .establishment`. Seems to be better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added location bias and it's working.

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#biasing_results_to_a_specific_region